# Error installing CocoaPod dependencies when setting up React Native Project on M1 Mac

Tags: react-native, rubygems, cocoapods

I have tried sudo gem install -n /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby@3.2/bin ffi cocoapods and brew install cocoapods but to no avail.

Any help will be appreciated.

The following is my error:

```
`
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error bundler: failed to load command: pod (/Users/cadyli/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/pod)
/Users/ana/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:108:in `<class:Array>': undefined method `deprecator' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)

  deprecate to_default_s: :to_s, deprecator: ActiveSupport.deprecator
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
Did you mean?  deprecate_constant
    from /Users/ana/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/activesupport-7.1.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/conversions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from /Users/ana/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from <internal:/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:38:in `require'
    from /Users/ana/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/bin/pod:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ana/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /Users/ana/Desktop/software projects/ecoexplorer/vendor/bundle/ruby/3.2.0/bin/pod:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:492:in `exec'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:34:in `dispatch'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/cli.rb:28:in `start'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.20/exe/bundle:37:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:117:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2_1/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/bundler-2.4.20/exe/bundle:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'`
```

I tried downgrading activesupport to an older version with sudo gem uninstall and then reinstalling, and also using brew to install everything instead.

Answer (score 1):

"The problem appears to be that CocoaPods isn't using an exact version of the activesupport gem and while it needs 7.0.8 it's pulling in 7.1.0 which breaks things. A workaround I found is to update the Gemfile in the root with the following:

```
gem 'activesupport', '~> 7.0', '<= 7.0.8'
```

Then run in the root

```
bundle update --bundler
```

then in the ios directory

```
bundle install
```

and

```
bundle exec pod install
```

and everything should work."

I had the same error and this worked for me

According to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/39832

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your current active support as such...

```
sudo gem uninstall activesupport
```

Then install the last stable version...

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 7.0.8
```

Then reinstall your cocoapods!

```
gem install cocoapods
```